# Android Extends:How to Extend import android.util.Log? and What its extends name?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

import android.util.Log

now i am using Log.e,Log.i in Android.and i am using the import android.util.Log;

```
Log.i("TIME", "USER " + user_id + " DATE: " + date);

Log.e("TIMESHEET", "USER ID: " + user_id + " DATE: " + date);

Log.d("TIMESHEET", "USER ID: " + user_id + " DATE: " + date);
```

our team to launch our product.

so we are using various log in our code.

for that i have to think.

i create a class and extend log.

by using override/implementation method i can access our needed things .

so for that i need to extend that log in my created class.

```
so if any way to make all Log in one class control please suggest.
```

thank,s in Advances.

Comment: what do you mean by extend: add a new function like Log.doMySpecilFunction()?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own class,say LogUtils, and create static functions for different type of logs. Use native Log function inside that class. For example :

```
/**
 * Utility methods to print log messages
 * 
 * @author shraddhas
 */
public class LogUtils
{
    /**
     * Send a message to the debug log if debugging is on
     */

    public static void trace(final String msg)
    {
        if (ApplicationConstants.IS_DEBUGGING_ON)
        {
            final String fullClassName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3].getClassName();
            final String className = fullClassName.substring(fullClassName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            final String methodName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3].getMethodName();
            final int lineNumber = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3].getLineNumber();

            Log.d(ApplicationConstants.LOG_TAG, "#" + lineNumber + " " + className + "." + methodName + "() : " + msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create another overloaded function to accept the type of the log so that you can print the logs depending upon its types accordingly.

Comment: is my log.e method will automatically called your trace method.how can i use LogUtils class.

Comment: LogUtils.trace("yourmessage here")

Comment: Aravintha, You should accept my answer, if it worked for you so that other users can take benefit of it, Thanks